# How can I identify a number of variable length with a regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I need a Perl regex to pull a number of between six and ten digits out of a string. The number will always follow a particular word followed by a space (case unknown).

For example, if the word I was looking for is 'string':

```
some random text blah blah blahSTRING 1234567890some more random text
```

Desired output:

```
1234567890
```

Another example:

```
yet more random textra ra rastring 654321hey hey my my
```

Desired output:

```
654321
```

I want to load the result into a variable.

Comment: Now just rewrite what you said in regexp terms - `string` then number(`\d`)  between six and ten digits long (`{6,10}`). You've practically presented entire regexp already just in plain words.

Comment: If you want to mark your question as "solved", please click the check mark next to the answer that provided the best answer, as a reward to that person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, between all the responses and a bit of googling I ended up with

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $string = 'sgtusadl;fdsas;adlhstring 12345678daf;slkdfja;dflk';
my ( $number ) = $string =~ m/string\s\d{6,10}/gi;
$number =~ s/[^0-9]//g;
print "number is $number\n";
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`/string ([0-9]{6,10})/i`

`string` matches **STRING** and **string** as the expression ends with i (case insenstive matching)

matches a space

`(`starts a capture group to capture the number you trying to get

`[0-9]{6,10}`matches a number with 6 to 10 places

https://regex101.com/r/mB1zF4/1

Answer (score 0):

Group 1 should contain your number with

```
/^.*string (\d+).*$/i
```